# Windows 10 batch file grief

Tags: command-line, pdf

I have this batch file called `open3.bat`:

```
@echo off

echo C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 9.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe /A  Page=55 example.pdf

pause
```

It's supposed to open Acrobat, load example.pdf and display page 55.

I run it by either using shell (open3,1) from excel VBA function or by typing open3 in a cmd window. Either way it does the same thing...nothing! Note if I paste the command in a cmd window it works as it should. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The `echo` command does what its name suggests — it produces echo:

```
C:\>echo Hello world!
Hello world!
```

If you want to launch a program, don't use the `echo` command and surround the path to the executable by quotes (because it contains spaces):

```
@echo off

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 9.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe" /A  Page=55 example.pdf

pause
```

Comment: You're going to need to quote the command.

Comment: @ajgringo619, of course, thanks, I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, But if I do that I get:

> C:\Program is not recognized as an *blah blah*

So I did this...
Create a link to Acrobat, dropped the echo as you suggest and my batch file now looks like this:

```
@echo off

Acrobat.exe.lnk /A  Page=55 C:\Chris\CAPCO\Mis\01ReceivedDocuments\example.pdf
```

... and this works!

Thanks again.

Comment: No need to create an alias, all what is need is *to surround the path to the executable by quotes (because it contains spaces) — see my corrected answer.